# Could not get search value from XML file using Python

Tags: python, xml

I need to search value from XML sheet as per user input using Python but its giving the blank value. Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('roomlist.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.findall(".//*[@roomname=\"cottage\"]"))
```

My XML file is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><roomlist>
  <location name="Bangalore">
    <room id="1uy92j908u092">
      <roomname> Aquarius </roomname>
      <noseats> 10 </noseats>
      <projectorscreen>yes</projectorscreen>
      <videoconf>yes</videoconf>
    </room>
  </location>
<location name="Bhubaneswar"><room id="131198912460"><roomname>cottage</roomname><noseats>5</noseats><projectorscreen>Yes</projectorscreen><videoconf>Yes</videoconf></room></location><location name="puri"><room id="509955554930"><roomname>room1</roomname><noseats>10</noseats><projectorscreen>No</projectorscreen><videoconf>Yes</videoconf></room></location></roomlist>
```

Here no data is coming. Here I need after searching all data should push into an array.

Comment: show the expected result

Comment: `$result=[{'lname':'Bhubaneswar','rname':'cottage','noseats':5,'projectorscreen':yes,'video':'yes'}]`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest : My expected output should come above.

Comment: No, after search my all data should look like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146846/discussion-between-satya-and-romanperekhrest).

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the values in your xml like below:

```
for roomname in root.iter('roomname'):
    print(roomname.text)
```

so you can check if it is there too

```
for roomname in root.iter('roomname'):
    if roomname.text == 'cottage':
        print(roomname.text)
```

Append names to a list:

```
lst = []
for roomname in root.iter('roomname'):
    lst.append(roomname.text)
```

In your case you need to traverse deeper into the tree. Below will access the attributes of the  room node

```
for child in root:
    for attr in child.find('room'):
        print(attr)
```

will output

```
<Element 'roomname' at 0x7f9c064d5090>
<Element 'noseats' at 0x7f9c064d50d0>
<Element 'projectorscreen' at 0x7f9c064d5150>
<Element 'videoconf' at 0x7f9c064d5190>
<Element 'roomname' at 0x7f9c064d5250>
<Element 'noseats' at 0x7f9c064d5290>
<Element 'projectorscreen' at 0x7f9c064d52d0>
<Element 'videoconf' at 0x7f9c064d5310>
<Element 'roomname' at 0x7f9c064d53d0>
<Element 'noseats' at 0x7f9c064d5410>
<Element 'projectorscreen' at 0x7f9c064d5450>
<Element 'videoconf' at 0x7f9c064d5490>
```

You can use the .text on the Element to create the dictionary or list you need

Also: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Good luck

Comment: In this case only one value is coming.

Comment: Here I need all value.

Comment: What exactly do you need your code to do? The first loop above will print all the room names , you can use the same loop construct to append the names to a list if that is what you need. please also consult the docs and maybe clarify your question somewhat.

Comment: here `roomname.text == 'cottage'` it should give these values `$result=[{'lname':'Bhubaneswar','rname':'cottage','noseats':‌​5,'projectorscreen':‌​yes,'videoconf':'yes'}]`.

Comment: Looks like you're getting help, judging from the comments. Hope above is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed an xslt stysheet with a python variable that injects the roomname you are looking for:

```
from lxml import etree
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    roomname = sys.argv[1]

xsl = etree.XML(f'''
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="location[room/roomname/text() = \'{roomname}\']">
        <xsl:text>[{{\'lname\':</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text>\', </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="room[roomname/text() = \'{roomname}\']/*" />
        <xsl:text>}}]&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="roomname[text() = \'{roomname}\']">
        <xsl:text>\'rname\':\'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:text>\', </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="noseats[preceding-sibling::roomname[text() = \'{roomname}\']]">
        <xsl:text>\'noseats\':</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="projectorscreen[preceding-sibling::roomname[text() = \'{roomname}\']]">
        <xsl:text>\'projectorscreen\':\'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:text>\', </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="videoconf[preceding-sibling::roomname[text() = \'{roomname}\']]">
        <xsl:text>\'videoconf\':\'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:text>\'</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
''')

transform = etree.XSLT(xsl)
with open("roomlist.xml") as f:
    print(transform(etree.parse(f)), end='')
```

Results:

```
$ ./roomlist.py room1
[{'lname':puri', 'rname':'room1', 'noseats':10, 'projectorscreen':'No', 'videoconf':'Yes'}]
```